# Изменение стиля отдельного слова

Tags: html, css

Добрый день. Такая проблема, если текст который разделен на span элемента,но т.к. в стилях прописано что они имеют смещение, то второй span отодвинут от первого. Кто подскажет, как сделать чтобы два span писались через пробел? Есть вариант добавить font вместо второго span.

Comment: что мешает задать класс второму span и убрать смещение?

Comment: вы хотите применить тег font ? только он исключён из HTML5 и при валидации будет выдавать ошибку

Comment: С этим и проблема)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте задать каждому из  класс или id.
Выполните это следующим образом:

```html
 <span class="first.span">Слово 1</span>
    <span class="second.span">Слово 2</span>
```

И пропишите отстутпы.

Comment: А если на нескольких страницах много таких элементов? каждому класс приписывать. Интересует вариант с добавлением тегов или изменение структуры данного участка

Comment: если вы хотите какое то слово стилизовать надо обернуть его в inline тег и потом уже его стилизовать , по другому ни как сделаешь , хоть на одной станице хоть на миллиарде страниц

Comment: Спасибо, что нибудь придумаю, используя это.